# My File Upload is Crashing My Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, openwrt

So I am trying to learn PHP and JS and wanted to build a file uploader for my home router running OpenWRT. I followed a lot of guides and built one that worked satisfactorily. However, when I started using bigger files (> 5mb) the router itself began to crash. When uploading an 11MB files, the router could crash anywhere between 30%-75% uploaded. I have edited php.ini like suggested by other posts on this site to support larger files and longer php script run times. I also have began to research chunking for file upload, but wanted to confirm where my problem was first. I apologize if my code is sloppy, I am still trying to figure everything out.

```js
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display = "block";
  var file = _("file1").files[0];
  if(_("file1").files[0] == null){
    _("status").innerHTML = "You Must Select a File";
  }
  else{
      // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "UPLOADER.php");  
    ajax.send(formdata);
  }
  
}
```

```html
 <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" class="inputfile" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
     <button onclick="uploadFile()" class="buttonUpload">Upload</button>
   </form>
```

And my PHP is

```php
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "Home/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

So it looks like my problem is that I need to perform the upload using chunking. I have seen all of the plugins such as resumable.js and plupload, but I would really like to understand how to do this within the context of the code I already have. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you trying to upload to the router? You have server running on a router? If so, have you checked the available space?

Comment: Yes I am uploading to the router. I have added substantial drive space to it (8 gigs).

Comment: Supposedly every router has event logs, error logs or something like that. Perhaps maybe the cpu or dram is limiting? Out of curiosity, you are not talking about about carrier grade router are you? Like the juniper t640 or something like that

Comment: No I am using a very cheap router! I will check out the log.

Comment: If it is my cpu or dram is there anyway to upload large files without upgrading the hardware? Could chunking be used then?

Comment: I think so, sending and writing by chunks shouldnt take much resources. You might as well check php memory limit before that

Comment: upload_max_filesize: 40M
post_max_size: 40M
max_input_time: 300
max_execution_time: 300 
This is inside my php.ini file